# Python multiprocessing and sys.argv

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, sys, concurrent.futures

Are `sys.argv` values passed to the branches of multiprocessing? What is the correct way of passing argv to all branches of the multiprocess?

Let's suppose I have two files: test1.py:

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    env = sys.argv[1]
else:
    env = 'test'
```

And main_code.py:

```
from test1 import *
import concurrent.futures


def f():
    if env == 'test':
        print('bu')
    else:
        print('not bu')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        for i in range(2):
            executor.submit(f)
```

I invoke from cmd main.code.py: `python main_code.py zzz`. Is the sys.argv[1] variable (which is 'zzz') passed on each invocation of `executor.submit(f)` as it was first obtained from import of text1.py? My confusion comes from the fact that concurrent.futures basically creates separate instances of threads of code by re-importing all the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, the [*spawn*](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=spawn#contexts-and-start-methods) context is the only way to create worker processes.

1. `sys.argv` are copied to worker processes once.
2. Not all files are re-imported. Only the modules are required to [unpickle](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#pickle.loads) the task function and arguments are imported.
3. In the worker, the original `__main__` is actually called `__mp_main__`.  After copying `sys.argv`, the worker import `__mp_main__`, which import `test`, so `env` is set correctly.
4. Though `multiprocessing` try to keep the environment similar, the worker process entry point is somewhere inside `multiprocessing.spawn`. Several items are mentioned there: `sys.argv`, `sys.path`, `os.getcwd()`. See `get_preparation_data()` and `prepare()` for details.
5. It can be verified with Task Manager or `ps` command that the worker process is started with different arguments.

I wrote a simple script called `mp.py` to print the arguments by running `python3 mp.py hello world`.

Output:

```
29836 process ['C:/xxxx/stackoverflow/mp.py'] <module '__main__' from 'C:/xxxx/stackoverflow/mp.py'>
29836 my name is main
29836 true main <module '__main__' from 'C:/xxxx/stackoverflow/mp.py'>
18464 process ['C:\\xxxx\\stackoverflow\\mp.py'] <module '__main__' (built-in)>
18464 worker <module '__mp_main__' from 'C:\\xxxx\\stackoverflow\\mp.py'>
```

mp.py:

```
from __future__ import annotations

import multiprocessing
import os
import sys
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def list_modules(who_am_i):
    the_main = sys.modules.get('__main__')
    print(os.getpid(), who_am_i, the_main)


def main():
    list_modules('true main')
    mp_context = multiprocessing.get_context('spawn')
    # mp_context = multiprocessing.get_context('fork')
    # mp_context = multiprocessing.get_context('forkserver')
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(1, mp_context=mp_context) as executor:
        executor.submit(list_modules, 'worker').result()

        time.sleep(100)


# This message is print when this module is loaded. (none in fork, once in forkserver, multiple times in spawn)
print(os.getpid(), "process", sys.argv, sys.modules.get('__main__'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Print once in the main process
    print(os.getpid(), "my name is main")
    main()
```

Comment: Can you provide a citation for "`sys.argv` are copied to worker processes once."?  I want more details, but I can't find doc on this anywhere.

Comment: @jjpr https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/760ec8940aabd6a7fc471bd913ea1ac501cc604b/Lib/multiprocessing/spawn.py#L154 and the following `preapre()`